# Strange behavior of String::Remove method

Tags: .net, visual-c++

I am using the String::Remove method to remove the first three characters of a String. However, I am receiving unexpected results from the method.

The first time my function runs it returns the string with the first two characters removed. The next time my function is run it returns the string with only the first character removed.

Are there hidden chars in the String? If so, how do I see them/remove them?

```
    String^ SendCommand(const String^ command)
    {
        lock l(thisLock);

        serialPort->WriteLine((String^) command);

        String^ response = serialPort->ReadLine();

        if (response[1] == CMD_ERROR_CHAR)
        {
            // Unknown command was sent
        }

        response = response->Remove(0, 3);

        return response;
    }
```

According to the debugger:

Run1:

(pre-Remove) response = ":A 0 TENTHS"

(post-Remove) response = "0 TENTHS" (no space in front of 0)

Run2:

(pre-Remove) response = ":A -725"

(post-Remove) response = " -725" (space in front of -)

**ANSWER:**

I figured it out, finally.

Apparently the Watch window will not hint at escape characters in a String. You will not know they exist unless you specifically index the character.

On Run2 I viewed response[0] in the Watch window and noticed a '\n' character. Even though response showed as ":A -725", it was actually "\n:A -725".

Caused me more trouble than it should have.

Comment: Should Run2 represent the incorrect output scenario? I only ask because it appears to be correct as it's removing ":A"...

Comment: Run1 removes ":A " (with a trailing space). Run 2 removes only ":A". Sorry, I'll make that more clear in the post.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the individual characters by index? otherwise you could also apply a TrimStart() to the string, just to be sure.

Comment: I'm almost sure its some non-graphic character being removed. I just don't know how to view non-graphic characters in the Visual Studio watch window.

Comment: I made a typo :). Changed it from 2 to 3 after I realized. They are read from the serial port.

Comment: @Mark Right-click on your variable, then select quickwatch. In that window, you can edit the variable expression from response to response[2] or anything else and reevaluate it.

Comment: @Mark, you should post this as an answer and accept it.